# Opencart shows variable instead text

Tags: variables, opencart

my store suddenly starts to show just the variables, instead the text of the variable.
i already check the controller, and it looks okay. 
the footer shows like this:

```
text_address
text_address_cnt
```

and the content of theses variables is

```
$_['text_address']      = 'Endereço';
$_['text_address_cnt']  = 'Endereço da sua loja';
```

the controller looks like:

```
$data['text_address'] = $this->language->get('text_address');
$data['text_address_cnt'] = $this->language->get('text_address_cnt');
```

anyone went through this? 
ps: store version 2.0.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a new store and works ok... Still don't know why this has happened.